# Changing Trac Attachment path

Tags: configuration, trac

How to change Trac's attachment path/folder?

I have virtualhosting:

```
/home/public_html/ - my www folder
/home/trac/ - trac projects folder
/home/trac/attachment/ - attachment folder
```

But I haven't access to it. When I attach files, I can't output it via Apache, because it stored out of apache htdocs.

And I can't use 'Alias' :/ (I haven't access to Apache config files, I have only .htaccess)
And I have access to Trac sources (but where is they stored, on .egg file?)

What I need to do? I want to move attachment folder to /home/public_html/attachment/

Answer (score 1):

You have got a few options:

- Move the attachments to the new location, then replace the `attachments` directory with a symlink to the new location.
- Move the attachments to the new location, then edit the Trac source code and change the path to the attachments. The path is currently [relative to the environment folder](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser//trunk/trac/attachment.py?rev=10696&marks=168-169#L166), so you will have to change that to an absolute path.
- Move the attachments to the new location, and implement a small plugin that monkey-patches the `Attachment._get_path()` method linked above.

But you shouldn't use any of these solutions, for the following reasons:

- Serving attachments with the web server directly bypasses all permission checks, so everyone will have access to all attachments.
- You will have issues with special characters in attachment file names (special characters are URL-encoded in the file name).
- Your installation will be more difficult to maintain if you patch the source code or monkey-patch it.

Why do you want to serve attachments from the web server? Will your users be downloading attachments very heavily?

The correct solution is to implement `X-Sendfile` in Trac, something we intend to do in the near future. See [#7894](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/7894#comment:9) for tracking progress.

Comment: Oh thank you for a great answer! Thanks! I'll try solutions! Trouble in my virtual hosting configs. I thas nginx proxy and it output any static, and when i try to download file, i've got error: 502 Bad Gateway

nginx/0.8.53

Comment: I have tried solution #2, but I've got trouble: File "/home/t/taglar/.python/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Trac-0.12.2-py2.6.egg/trac/web/main.py", line 511, in _dispatch_request .... :(

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing this unless you have a very good reason to do so. Why don't you want Trac to serve attachments?

Comment: I can't. Virtualhosting's nginx proxy closed this connection and I can't get attached files. Every time I try to get file by link /raw-attachments/ticket/.../.. <- ive got only this error: 502 Bad Gateway nginx/0.8.53. Nginx tries to send me a file, but It can't or something like this... I don't know. :(